Default modifiers in Smarty 5.3
I wanted to upgrade Smarty that I use in my project. I download Smarty 5.3 and now I can't use modifiers like "count" anymore. How can I add support for default modifiers?
There is no directory like plugins to use with addDefaultModifiers.

Finally, I found the solution, my function that extend Smarty:
function addPhpModifiers( &$smarty )
    {

        $functions = array(
            'array_key_exists',
            'ceil',
            'count',
            'date',
            'explode',
            'floatval',
            'htmlentities',
            'md5',
            'in_array',
            'ip2long',
            'is_array',
            'is_numeric',
            'intval',
            'json_encode',
            'mb_strtoupper',
            'md',
            'nl2br',
            'number_format',
            'round',
            'strip_tags',
            'stripslashes',
            'strlen',
            'strstr',
            'strtolower',
            'strtotime',
            'strtoupper',
            'trim',
            'urlencode',
        );

        foreach($functions as &$f) {
            $smarty->registerPlugin('modifier', $f, $f);
        }

    }

